# HealthKit: create a predicate for specific sources and date range

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I need to search HealthKit for data from a specific given data source. However when a user has not logged in for a long time, I don't want too much data, so I only want to go back a specific period of time. How can I generate a predicate for an `HKQuery` that both specifies a source (using `HKQuery predicateForObjectsFromSources`) and specifies a date range (using `HKQuery predictForSamplesWithStartDate...`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine multiple `NSPredicate` instances using the `andPredicateWithSubpredicates:` or the `orPredicateWithSubpredicates:` class methods on `NSCombinedPredicate`.  See the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/) for more details.